# Convert SQL to Rails Query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to convert the following SQL Query to something Rails can understand:

```
SELECT posts.* FROM 
(
SELECT group_id, MAX(updated_at) AS updated_at FROM posts WHERE group_id IN (4, 6, 9) GROUP BY group_id
) AS latest_posts 
INNER JOIN posts ON 
latest_posts.group_id = posts.group_id AND 
latest_posts.updated_at = posts.updated_at;
```

The name of the model is `Post`. My attempt:

```
Post.select("(SELECT group_id, MAX(updated_at) AS updated_at FROM posts WHERE group_id IN (4, 6, 9) GROUP BY group_id) AS latest_posts")
.joins('INNER JOIN posts ON latest_posts.group_id = posts.group_id AND latest_posts.updated_at = posts.updated_at')
```

The error:

```
Error:
UserTest#test_feed_should_have_the_right_posts:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DuplicateAlias: ERROR:  table name "posts" specified more than once

    test/models/user_test.rb:100:in `block in <class:UserTest>'
```

Update: Close but no cigar. Frustrating.

```
irb(main):046:0> Post.select("posts.* FROM (SELECT group_id, MAX(updated_at) AS updated_at FROM posts WHERE group_id IN (4, 6, 9) GROUP BY group_id) AS latest_posts").joins("INNER J
OIN posts  ON  latest_posts.group_id = posts.group_id  AND  latest_posts.updated_at = posts.updated_at")
```

Produces:

```
SELECT posts.* FROM 
(SELECT group_id, MAX(updated_at) AS updated_at FROM posts WHERE group_id IN (4, 6, 9) GROUP BY group_id)
 AS latest_posts 
FROM "posts" 
INNER JOIN posts  
ON  latest_posts.group_id = posts.group_id  AND  latest_posts.updated_at = posts.updated_at
```

Comment: You could call `.to_sql` at the end of a chain, and compare SQLs

Comment: Perhaps if you alias the two different instances of the "posts" table that are used (ie. the first one in the "SELECT" statement, and the second in the "INNER JOIN", then it will probably work as you expect it to.  I'll post as an answer, so you see what I mean - although I'm not 100% certain

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Post.select("(SELECT group_id, MAX(updated_at) AS updated_at FROM posts p1 WHERE group_id IN (4, 6, 9) GROUP BY group_id) AS latest_posts")
.joins('INNER JOIN posts p2 ON latest_posts.group_id = p2.group_id AND latest_posts.updated_at = p2.updated_at')
```

I suspect that by aliasing the two separate references to the "posts" table, then the query will be acceptable to Rails

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - did you try my actual suggestion?  The updates that you've added to your question are structuring the queries in slightly different ways, but that's not what I suggested

Comment: Yes I tried it, here's the error: `Error:
UserTest#test_feed_should_have_the_right_posts:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "latest_posts"
LINE 1: ...LECT 1 AS one FROM "posts" INNER JOIN posts p2 ON latest_pos...
                                                             ^

    test/models/user_test.rb:100:in `block in <class:UserTest>
`

Comment: It looks like the syntax of the query that you're running in that example is different to the syntax of the original query - have you changed it?  It makes it difficult to try and interpret whether aliasing the table names is an issue, or you have introduced a new syntax problem that's causing the error.  What is the full query that you tried to execute, that caused that error?

Comment: `Post.select("(SELECT group_id, MAX(updated_at) AS updated_at FROM posts p1 WHERE group_id IN (4, 6, 9) GROUP BY group_id) AS latest_posts").joins('INNER JOIN posts p2 ON latest_posts.group_id = p2.group_id AND latest_posts.updated_at = p2.updated_at')`

Comment: Hi - no, what I meant was that it's showing part of the query that you're running as ...LECT 1 AS one FROM "posts" ..... that's not part of the query that was in my answer.  I wanted to see what the full query is that you're now running, that's causing the error

Comment: Interestingly, I found a workaround using `Post.find_by_sql`, with my SQL statement copy and pasted. However, the documentation says that this should be a last resort, due to a possible change in the database used: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class. I really appreciate the help by the way.

Comment: I don't quite understand - the error message doesn't seem to correspond with that exact query.  Are there multiple different queries running, and the error messages relates to a different one ..... why does the error message include that bit  .... LECT 1 AS one from "posts"?  If it's reporting an error with some syntax near that part of the query, then there must be a different query that you're running that's raising the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231906/discussion-between-izaguirrejoe-and-craig).